Does a longer wing produce same lift as a wider wing with the same total area?
Considering the image below, as shown, both wings have the same total area but with different
different measures.
Do they produce the same lift, or which wing produces more lift and which one makes more drag? (notice both have the same max thickness)


Yes. This answer explains why. (Not writing this as an answer because I’m basically just linking something else, plus I didn’t go into drag)

Related What is (theoretically) the most efficient shape for an aircraft, assuming you don't have to carry any cargo?

It depends, and what do you mean for "Area"? Above? Below? One problem you are ignoring is about not going straight into air flow. if you are pitching (up and down) you see that the things may be different, wider wings may cause turbulence or just disrupt flow on controls on tail. There are a lot of design decisions and trade-off.

The share of wing close to one of the tips, relative to the total wing area, is larger in the long chord / short span version. Since the pressure difference between top and bottom is smaller near the tips, the long span version produces more lift at the same angle of attack.
However, the maximum angle of attack is also lower on the long span version, so the long chord version will gain a bit of extra lift before both stall. If we compare both wings at the same speed, the long chord version is also helped by its larger Reynolds Number, which helps to delay flow separation.
In the end, it will be other details like nose radius of the airfoil and relative thickness which determine which wing will create most lift. The results should be very close if both wings are designed and built correctly.
Drag: The long span version will produce less drag at high lift coefficients while the long chord version will be slightly ahead at zero lift. However, the long span version will be heavier because it will have higher bending loads, so it needs to produce a bit more lift to only support itself. Since both wings have the same maximum thickness and are rather small, the difference in weight will be small. So it is safe to say that the long span version will produce less drag at most of its useful operating points.


Wing A has a bigger span which gives a lower induced drag.
Wing B has a lower thick to chord ratio (aka thickness ratio) which in general gives lower drag and lower $C_{l_{max}}$. The lower aspect ratio will also give smoother stall characteristics.

Hard to tell which configuration is going to give less drag, also considering that those wings will presumably be attached to a fuselage and a tailplane, both of which will substantially contribute to the overall drag.

The lift equation has area, but also coefficient of lift.

Lift = density × area × (airfoil type × angle of attack) × velocity$^2$

At equal angles of attack, the higher aspect wing will produce more lift if it's Reynolds number is sufficiently high.

Reynolds number equal Velocity × chord/1.46 x 10$^5$

At Reynolds number > around 200,000 the mechanism of lift changes from action/reaction deflection of air off the bottom to a combination of "bottom lift" and lift created by low pressure above the wing.
One can see how Reynolds number affects the lift to drag ratio of an airfoil.
At lower Reynolds number the lower aspect ratio might actually be more efficient, but lower tip and fuselage interferences favor the higher aspect wing.
